# Book Identification: 80s or 90s horror

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I was wondering if you can help me remember this particular book I read when I was younger.

It was about a girl who played lacrosse.  She lived in a New England setting, I believe.  She often experienced supernatural things -- they happened in her neighborhood.  When she'd get a bad feeling about an area or right before an event, the colors of her hair (silver, gold, and I think brown?) would separate.  She had a younger sister who weaved a hair in her toothbrush, so she boiled her toothbrush to make it germ-free and instead melted it.  She also befriended an elderly woman who would talk to her from time to time.

I think maybe there was a picture of a haunted house on the cover.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like *The Fog* by Caroline B Cooney, published in 1989.  It was part of the Point Horror series when I read it.  I couldn't tell you what the cover looked like but it's set in Maine and the main character, Christina, did have the silver, gold and brown hair.

It's since been republished as [*Fog: Fog, Snow, and Fire*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GOTN2YC).  Plot summary from Amazon:

> Christina Romney is thirteen, with a personality that matches her
> unruly but charming tri-colored hair. She is about to start seventh
> grade, and for kids from Maine’s Burning Fog Island, that means
> leaving their little white schoolhouse for regular classrooms and life
> on the mainland. Everyone assures Christina it will be a fantastic
> year. Mainland school offers great advantages, after all:
> extracurricular activities other than boating and fishing, a gym, a
> cafeteria, and more kids her age. Best of all, this year the boarding
> students will live at the historic Schooner Inne, a former sea
> captain’s house (and now a bed and breakfast) recently bought by the
> school’s charismatic new principal and his wife, Mr. and Mrs.
> Shevvington.
>
> But Christina is apprehensive. She adores the wildness and excitement
> of her island life. Boarding with her island friends will surely help:
> Anya, a beautiful senior, fifteen-year-old Benji, the aspiring
> lobsterman, and his crush-worthy younger brother Michael. But
> Christina’s apprehension sharpens when Benji and Michael aren’t as
> friendly as they used to be on the island, and Anya starts acting so
> strangely it seems she is slowly losing her mind. Christina is
> increasingly certain the Shevvingtons are behind all of these changes.
> But no one else can see the Shevvingtons’ eerie behavior—not other
> teachers, not her parents, not even her fellow island kids. Is Anya
> the one going crazy in the Schooner Inne—or is it Christina?